# Leads and reaches

Tags: meaning-in-context

Sherlock Holmes could use leads in order to reach a criminal during an investigation? Does a reach mean something in the context of an investigation or in a process of reaching the truth about a conspiracy theory? I was watching an Asmongold's video the other day about Bored Yacht Monkeys Club and he repeatedly said *that's a reach* when an argument for a conspiracy theory was made. Example sentences

> - There is a fingerprint of his cousin on the lipstick.
> - We have a lead!

> - The solution to the riddle indicates suggestion to the number 1488
> - Chat, that's a reach.

In WordNet dictionary *lead* is defined as *evidence pointing to a possible solution*. In UrbanDictionary someone defined *reach* as *Term used when someone tries to [relate] [one thing] to another using [completely irrelevant] evidence and information.*

Do these uses make any sense? What are the differences between those meanings, what do you think?

Comment: **Lead** in this sense is a normal word to use in the context of a criminal investigation, but **reach** looks like modern slang; I can't imagine it being used of Sherlock Holmes unless he was actually trying to make contact with a suspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple definitions for **reach** as a noun and as a verb, depending on the context. In your first example:

> Sherlock Holmes could use leads in order to reach a criminal during an investigation.

**reach** might mean to actually contact the criminal. It often indicates that the person is either far away, in a place where it's difficult to receive messages, or in a different kind of place (like a spiritual world). Or, it might mean to **reach a conclusion** about the identity of the criminal.

Used as a noun, in this context, **reach** means a a conclusion that you could possibly arrive at, but only under perfect conditions, or if you made a series of unlikely assumptions, or if something improbable actually happened. The word *stretch* is a good synonym, and more commonly used I think, at least in American English.